# when I'm finished / when I finish / when I finish with it

Tags: subjunctives, future-tense

Instead of

> This is a good book. Would you like to read it when I'm finished?

could I say either of the following?

> Would you like to read it when I finish?
>
> Would you like to read it when I finish with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are correct. As "when" is a time word, when used to talk about the present or future, it can be followed either by the simple present tense (***When I finish**", or **When I'm** ****finished****"-simple present in the passive voice) or it can be followed by the present perfect tense ( **"When I have finished)*** **As for "When I finish with it", it's correct, as it means "when I no longer need to use it" You could also say" When I finish it"**strong text

Comment: Glad to help nima!

Answer (score 3):

> When I'm finished, would you like to read it?
>   When I finish, would you like to read it?
>   When I finish with it, would you like to read it?
>   When I'm finished with it, would you like to read it?

I think all of those would be acceptable. However, if we use *done* instead of *finished*, only these versions are acceptable:

> When I'm done, would you like to read it?
>   When I'm done with it, would you like to read it?

To use *do* in this way, you'd need more context:

> I should finish the book this weekend. When I do, would you like to read it?

---

<sub>NOTE: I've change the order of the phrases, but that can be reversed, too, and my answer would still hold:

*Would you like to read it when I'm finished?* etc.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to read it when I finish?
Would you like to read it when I finish with it?

The latter sentence implies to me that the reader might not want the book back after they have read it.

For instance if you were to say in reply, "Do you mind if I keep it for a month or two?", I'd expect the first answer to be "That's OK, return it when you can." and the second "Don't worry, I don't want it back."